# jQuery get deepest inner element

Tags: jquery, html

Find most inner `ul` to insert some more `li`s. I'm not sure about the depth of th `ul`.

Is there any jQuery API to find most `inner` element of the divs.

```
<ul class="optiongroup" "label"="Solutions">
   <li><label>Solutions</label></li>
   <ul class="optiongroup" "label"="Other Solutions">
   <li><label>Other Solutions</label></li>
      <ul class="optiongroup" "label"="Publishing">       <li><label>Publishing</label></li>
  // Append some <li>'s here 
      </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: That html is invalid. No there is no simple approach without having some sort of classes or attributes to help. Otherwise will need a recursive loop to find deepest

Comment: <label>Solutions</label> directed inside the Ul is wrong one. It should comes only inside <li><label>Solutions</label></li>.

Comment: @charlietfl - Yes, Actually one of my recursive function generate this structure.

Comment: I guess no API for specific scenario you specified. Also are you sure that all the `ul` are child of parent  `ul`? I mean are there any chances of siblings `ul` inside parent `ul`?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no API thing for it.. Risky, generating code in recursive functions... some machines might block.. do the `ul` elements have a maximum of 1 other `ul` inside? That would make it easier to write a function for

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest- Actually, have to iterate recursively over a nested complex json to generate this structure.

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest that is a ridiculous statement

Comment: I'm currently in a somewhat same situation, I've got a model description in json and I have to draw in a canvas using that model's properties. The thing is, I have to loop every single child, and the child of that child.. and that one's childs.... XD but there are more childs per child possible..

Comment: @Laxmikant when you create the elements keep track of levels in each iteration and add classes like `level-4` or something like that so you can find them easily again

Comment: @charlietfl - Yes, That makes sense. Will add it. Thanks

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest - I guess, in the future, there could be any number of `ul`s.  inside a ul. Thanks for pointing out that. Will go ahead with  charlietfl's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function finds the leaf `ul` elements in a `context` and does something for them:

```
function handleInnerUL(context) {
    //finds all inner ul elements
    var innerContext = context.find("ul");
    //processes inner ul elements
    innerContext.each(function() {
        //if ul does not have inner ul, then do something
        if (innerContext.find("ul").length === 0) {
            //Do something
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to do this by depth number, then do it this way:

```
handleInnerUL(context) {
    //initialize helpers
    var innerSelector = "ul";
    var innerContext = context.find(innerSelector);
    var depthmostContext = null;
    //while inner level exists, process into it
    while (innerContext.length > 0) {
        //store the innermost depth ul found
        depthmostContext = innerContext;
        innerSelector += " ul";
        innerContext = context.find(innerSelector);
    }
    //do something for them
    depthmostContext.each(function() {
        //do something
    });
}
```